# ML Flow cannot start, tracebacks with list index out of range

Tags: gunicorn, mlflow

Clean install of MLFlow on conda mac. It launches fine:

```
(base) AZMacbook ~ % mlflow server --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 

[2024-02-08 15:30:40 -0500] [90782] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2024-02-08 15:30:40 -0500] [90782] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8080 (90782)
[2024-02-08 15:30:40 -0500] [90782] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-02-08 15:30:40 -0500] [90783] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90783
[2024-02-08 15:30:40 -0500] [90784] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90784
[2024-02-08 15:30:41 -0500] [90786] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90786
[2024-02-08 15:30:41 -0500] [90787] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90787
```

But I cannot access the web url. It throws a 500 error.

```
[2024-02-08 15:30:48 -0500] [90786] [ERROR] Error handling request /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/az/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/Users/az/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 168, in handle_request
    resp, environ = wsgi.create(req, client, addr,
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alanzhao/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 183, in create
    path_info = path_info.split(script_name, 1)[1]
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```